# Placing a DIV multiple times and with random position

Tags: jquery, random, background, frontend

I need to place a div (actually a small image of a cloud) at random positions (as a background). The background should hence have multiple small clouds placed everywhere on the page as a "**realistic sky background**".

Later on I would try to apply a [parallax scroll plugin](http://jonraasch.com/blog/scrolling-parallax-jquery-plugin) on those divs .

Thanks!

Comment: What's the question? Just make some divs, `position: absolute` them and give them random `top` and `left` values. Be sure to set the `z-index`.

Comment: Thanx for the reply! Actually I have no idea, I'm just a designer that understands JS and JQuery =) It would be awesome if someone just could give me a dead-simple example of it can be done. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute position divs with background image. Just have to change their z-index to negative value or 0 you must test it. And if it does not work try changing the content z-index too, but to higher value.

The absolute position will give you the chance for animating top and left css values.

You can use jquery animations.

Random cords can be asumed by

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*(maxNumber+1));
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply! Actually I have no idea, I'm just a designer that understands JS and JQuery =) It would be awesome if someone just could give me a dead-simple example of it can be done. Thanx!